# Using \hypersetup in \maketitle produces no metadata

Tags: xetex, hyperref, metadata

In a document class for XeLaTeX, I invoke `hyperref` in \AtBeginDocument so that it gets loaded last, and I reset the link colours at the same time. I then use `\hypersetup` in `\maketitle` to set the PDF metadata.

In the MWE below, I don't get any PDF metadata in the output (pdfinfo returns no title or author). I have obviously misunderstood something about \hypersetup with metadata, but what?

test.cls =========================================================================================

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2017/04/15]
\ProvidesClass{test}[v0.1 test hypersetup]
%
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[a4paper]{report}
%
\def\MY@customtitle{\relax}
\def\MY@customauthor{\relax}
%
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\gdef\MY@customtitle{#1}}
\renewcommand{\author}[1]{\gdef\MY@customauthor{#1}}
%
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \RequirePackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}%
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue,
              urlcolor=purple,
              citecolor=magenta}%
}
%
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \begin{titlepage}
    \MY@customtitle
    \par\bigskip
    \MY@customauthor
    \par\vfill
  \end{titlepage}
  \pagenumbering{roman}
  \hypersetup{pdfauthor={\MY@customauthor},
              pdftitle={\MY@customtitle},
              pdfcreator={XeLaTeX}}%
}
\endinput
```

test.tex =================================================================================

```
\documentclass{test}
\begin{document}
\title{Test document}
\author{A.N. Author}
\maketitle
Here is a link on some \href{http://latex.silmaril.ie}{text}
\end{document}
```

(Also, very weirdly, it fails to honour the colour purple, despite the xcolor documentation sayin that it's available by default).

Comment: as you are not loading xcolor it isn't really relevant what the documentation says about purple.

Comment: I assumed hyperref would load xcolor like it normally does because I requested [colorlinks]. Most of the time hyperref _does_ load xcolor, and barfs because if you need a palette, you have to force it in with `\PassOptionsToPackage` to avoid the clash.

Comment: hyperref never loads xcolor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently hyperref will write the metadata at the end of the first page to the pdf. Your \hypersetup is after the titlepage environment and so on the second page. This is too late.

Comment: Ooh, thank you. I had missed that.